Coding a 6 using tikz
I have been working on some code that attempts to make a handwritten looking 6 using tikz.

The top line of the first example is too straight.
The top line of the second example isn't smooth.
This is what I am aiming for:

Smooth top, and the circle bit at the bottom half of the overall height of the figure.
Does anyone know a good approach for making the 6 using tikz?
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

% First TikZ picture
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [white] (0,-0.5) -- (0,0.5) -- (0.6,0.5);
    \draw[ultra thick, line cap=round] (0.2,-0.25) circle[x radius=0.25, y radius=0.25];
    \draw[ultra thick, line cap=round] (-0.015,-0.12) -- coordinate[pos=0.5](-mid)(0.3,0.4);
\end{tikzpicture}

% Add some space between the images
\hspace{1cm}

% Second TikZ picture
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [draw=none] (0,-0.5) -- (0,0.5) -- (0.6,0.5);
    \draw[ultra thick, line cap=round] (0.25,-0.25) circle[x radius=0.23, y radius=0.23];
    \coordinate (A) at (0.1, 0.18);
    \coordinate (B) at (0.25, 0.35);
    \draw[ultra thick, line cap=round] (0.024,-0.2) .. controls (A) and (B) .. (0.42,0.4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


er ... can you explain why? making a character with tikz will render it inaccessible to screen readers etc. and there are various hand-writing fonts available already. if there really isn't one you can use, tikz would not be my choice of software to create it. for smoothness, see the hobby package. but you would be much better looking at metapost, say. (or fontforge.)

Quite far through a project and all other numbers have been made with tikz to create tracing worksheets where the lines are replaced with dashed lines to support students.

well I guess that means accessibility isn't germane. presumably blind students get different worksheets. if you're committed to tikz, look at hobby.

\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[ultra thick, line cap=round] 
  (1.0,2.0) to[out=180, in=180, looseness=1.2] 
  (0.5,0.0) to[out=0, in=0, looseness=1.9] 
  (0.5,1.0) to[out=180, in=180, looseness=1.7]
  (0.5,0.0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



I got there!

\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
   
   \begin{scope}[xscale=1, yscale=1.5] % Scale y-axis to create an ellipse
        \draw[ultra thick] (0.215,-0.82) arc[start angle=185, end angle=90, radius=3cm];
    \end{scope}
   
     \draw[ultra thick] (2,-1) ellipse [x radius=1.8cm, y radius=1.65cm];

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

